# Extended search and replace in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to search in a database a custom string and replace it with a new one?
The string I'm searching can appear in different tables and sometimes in different columns of the same table, so basically what i ned to do is search and replace everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query like:

```
UPDATE [table_name] 
SET [field_name] = 
REPLACE([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

Repeat for every relevant table and/or field in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help but, is there a way to automate this for all tables in the database? and the fields... In my database the string i want to change can appear in different tables and in different fields of the same table.

Comment: Probably not in SQL. You might need to script it in whatever flavor of scripting language (php, perl, shell, python, etc) you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in PHP:

```
<?php

// edit this line to add old and new terms which you want to be replaced
$search_replace = array( 'old_term' => 'new_term', 'old_term2' => 'new_term2' );

//change the localhost,username,password and database-name according to your db
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database-name") or die(mysql_error());

$show_tables = mysql_query( 'SHOW TABLES' );
while( $st_rows = mysql_fetch_row( $show_tables ) ) {
    foreach( $st_rows as $cur_table ) {
        $show_columns = mysql_query( 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM ' . $cur_table );
        while( $cc_row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $show_columns ) ) {
            $column = $cc_row['Field'];
            $type = $cc_row['Type'];
            if( strpos( $type, 'char' ) !== false || strpos( $type, 'text' ) !== false ) {
                foreach( $search_replace as $old_string => $new_string ) {
                    $replace_query = 'UPDATE ' . $cur_table .
                        ' SET ' .  $column . ' = REPLACE(' . $column .
                        ', \'' . $old_string . '\', \'' . $new_string . '\')';
                    mysql_query( $replace_query );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo 'replaced';
mysql_free_result( $show_columns );
mysql_free_result( $show_tables );
mysql_close( $mysql_link );

?>
```

[Source](https://github.com/micahbolen/PHP-MySQL-Search-And-Replace)